# How to enable "position:fixed" for elements that are within an isotope item?

Tags: position, z-index, fixed, jquery-isotope

I am currently using *isotope* to organize my portfolio. I found that if I decided to place elements inside an isotope item and make these elements' position as fixed, they will not displace fixed on screen. Instead, these elements will use the isotope item's x and y position as the initial screen position. For instance, if I place an element as position:fixed and left:0; top:0; this element will not display on the top left corner of the screen. Instead, it will display on the top left corner of the isotope item.

Another issue I encounter is that the z-index of the element inside of the isotope item is not independent. If I give the element a greater z-index than other isotope items, say if the element  has the z-index of 100, and all isotope items have the z-index of 10, the "portfolio_display" will still display behind all isotope items.

To explain what I am trying to achieve:

I want to make the isotope items become clickable, and when it is being activated, a full screen portfolio display will show up and take over the screen.

I do know plugin such as lightbox 2 will work. However, I like to have my portfolio display have much richer functions than lightbox 2. I want to put case study, images, videos, in the full screen mode, and each screen can be format like web page. So my method is to put multiple formatted divs into an isotope item, and use javescript (written by myself) to control their visibility and scrolling. This method works until I started integrate isotope to my portfolio.

I imagine isotope created a little "web page" inside of the bigger "web page" so it dictates the z-index and the position inside of its own. I like to know if I can disable isotope's dictation to its sub elements without breaking its great functionality.

Thank you.

Comment: Please always show a bare-bones online sandbox or jsfiddle so people can see the problems live and can change code on the fly to help. You should show some coding effort on a coding Q&A site...

Answer (score 1):

For your full-window display purposes, you can change [the modal overlay technique in this demo](http://www.hopfnordin.se/demo.html) to your purposes. No plugin needed, you can put whatever you want to show in there, not just use it as an easy self-made modal.

Comment: And - you got an answer. Did it answer your question?